# Question mark in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across this piece of code in a github repository, and I couldn't quite understand this little piece of code, what '?Function' means?

```
handleCardNumberBlur = ({ onBlur }: { onBlur?: ?Function } = { onBlur: null }) 
    => (e: SyntheticInputEvent<*>) => {
        const { customTextLabels } = this.props;
        if (!payment.fns.validateCardNumber(e.target.value)) {
            this.setFieldInvalid(customTextLabels.invalidCardNumber || 'Card number is invalid');
        }

        const { cardNumberInputProps } = this.props;
        cardNumberInputProps.onBlur && cardNumberInputProps.onBlur(e);
        onBlur && onBlur(e);
}
```

So, please tell me if I understand correctly,

```
{ onBlur }: { onBlur?: ?Function } = { onBlur: null }
```

This means that the onBlur variable if defined, leave as it is, if undefined is of type function and to start of with its value is null?

Answer (score 0):

That ain't Javascript.  It's [Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/).